# How to do multiple search for alist of strings in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of strings and I want to search for each one of them [separately] in all files (*.c or *.h) automaticaly inside a folder
for example

```
variableNumber1
variableNumber2
variableNumber3
variableNumber4
```

and results will be something like that (with every file where it is found)

```
Search "variableNumber4" (34 hits in 4 files)
Search "variableNumber3" (6 hits in 5 files)
Search "variableNumber2" (7 hits in 6 files)
Search "variableNumber1" (4 hits in 1 files)
```

I tried a macros recording the action "search in file" I save it and then went to the code behinde and I found the following

```
<Macro name="searchTest" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="variableNumber1" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1653" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="the_path_of_MyFolder" />
            <Action type="3" message="1652" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="*.c*"" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="32" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1656" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
```

in action number "1601" the ***sParam*** is varaibleNumber1 that means each time I run the macro I'm getting all the time resulats for "variableNumber1"

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F, then Find in files. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Toto yes but I want to the process to be automated so i don't have to search for each one manualy

Comment: I see. I'm afraid this can't be done.You may find `\b(?:var1|var2|var3)\b` but this will display all matches.